# Fetch data from external function not working in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch

I try to reduce my code by adding this code in an external/general function :

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api-out/5_settings", {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'PATCH',
      mode: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ theme })
      }).then((response) => {
      console.log(response)
      return response
  })
},[theme])
```

When I use this code from an external function like this from another file even the same file :

> Call

```
fetchData(theme, "/api-out/5_settings")
```

> The function in general file

```
export function fetchData(out, link) {
          fetch(link, {
          credentials: 'include',
          method: 'PATCH',
          mode: 'same-origin',
          headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ out })
      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          return response
      })
}
```

It does not work. It's more strange. The response is exactly the same but data is not applied in the API.
So, the action works but the data sent looks wrong.

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "https://website.com/api-out/5_settings", redirected: false, status: 202, ok: true, …}
```

Do you have any idea ?
The function may replace the fetch and then inside the useEffect.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You are talking about retrieving data but issuing a PATCH request instead of a GET.

Comment: It's for updating not getting. It works. The problem is why it does not work with the same code in a function in another file.